# Error EXC_BAD_ACCESS with scrollViewDidScroll

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uikit

I must be missing something obvious, because I have a very simple app the generates an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

I have a first view controller inside a navigation controller.
From there, I push a second view controller with a UITableView.
In this second view controller, I have implemented the scrollViewDidScroll delegate method.

When I scroll down to the bottom of the table, and then go back to the first view controller, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Here is the code of the first view controller:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    UIButton* button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.bounds.size.width, 50)];
    button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [button setTitle:@"Push tableView" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void) buttonClick {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[ViewController2 new] animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Here is the code of the second view controller

```
@interface ViewController2 () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView* tableView;

@end

@implementation ViewController2

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 20;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSLog(@"scroll");
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString* identifer = @"identifer";
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifer];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifer];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d", indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

The error is not generated when I comment out scrollViewDidScroll method, or if I do not scroll until the end of the table before returning to the first view controller.

I am using XCode 6 (with iOS SDK 8), and have tested on iOS 7 and iOS 8 simulator and physical devices.

Does this make any sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set to nil the datasource and delegate properties of the UITableView in the dealloc method of your second view controller. The UITableView is sending some message to the delegate after it has already been deallocated.

So, something like this in your second view controller:

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    self.tableView.dataSource = nil;
    self.tableView.delegate = nil;
}
```

Comment: I just don't understand why didn't Apple update those properties to `weak`?!